# PHPWord through composer on wamp

Tags: php, composer-php, phpword

I know there are many subject about composer but I won't be able to install phpword through composer.

Basically I need to install PHPWord to create word on my network server.

I install wamp on my computer, install composer and create a new folder on www.

Let's say the main directory is : www/test/

I write a composer.json file :

```
{
"require": {
   "phpoffice/phpword": "v0.13.*"
}
```

}

And with command line, I tried composer install :

> Failed loading c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.6.19/ext/php_xdebug-2.4.0-5.6-vc11-nts.dll
>   Loading composer repositories with package information
>   Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
>   Package operations: 6 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
>     - Installing pclzip/pclzip (2.8.2): Loading from cache
>     - Installing phpoffice/common (v0.2.6): Loading from cache
>     - Installing zendframework/zend-stdlib (2.4.13): Loading from cache
>     - Installing zendframework/zend-validator (2.4.13): Loading from cache
>     - Installing zendframework/zend-escaper (2.4.13): Loading from cache
>     - Installing phpoffice/phpword (v0.13.0): Loading from cache
>   zendframework/zend-stdlib suggests installing zendframework/zend-eventmanager (To support aggregate hydrator usage)
>   zendframework/zend-stdlib suggests installing zendframework/zend-serializer (Zend\Serializer component)
>   zendframework/zend-stdlib suggests installing zendframework/zend-servicemanager (To support hydrator plugin manager usage)
>   zendframework/zend-stdlib suggests installing zendframework/zend-filter (To support naming strategy hydrator usage)
>   zendframework/zend-validator suggests installing zendframework/zend-db (Zend\Db component)
>   zendframework/zend-validator suggests installing zendframework/zend-filter (Zend\Filter component, required by the Digits validator)
>   zendframework/zend-validator suggests installing zendframework/zend-i18n (Zend\I18n component to allow translation of validation error messages as well as to use the various Date validators)
>   zendframework/zend-validator suggests installing zendframework/zend-math (Zend\Math component)
>   zendframework/zend-validator suggests installing zendframework/zend-resources (Translations of validator messages)
>   zendframework/zend-validator suggests installing zendframework/zend-servicemanager (Zend\ServiceManager component to allow using the ValidatorPluginManager and validator chains)
>   zendframework/zend-validator suggests installing zendframework/zend-session (Zend\Session component)
>   zendframework/zend-validator suggests installing zendframework/zend-uri (Zend\Uri component, required by the Uri and Sitemap\Loc validators)
>   phpoffice/phpword suggests installing ext-gd2 (Allows adding images)
>   phpoffice/phpword suggests installing dompdf/dompdf (Allows writing PDF)
>   Writing lock file
>   Generating autoload files

So now I've got a new folder call vendor with autoload.php and many folder inside (zendframework, phpoffice...)

When I try to go to a phpword example, I've got this error :

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Could not find file '/autoload.php'. It is generated by Composer. Use 'install --prefer-source' or 'update --prefer-source' Composer commands to move forward.' in C:\wamp\www\Nouveau dossier (2)\vendor\phpoffice\phpword\bootstrap.php on line 22
>   ( ! ) Exception: Could not find file '/autoload.php'. It is generated by Composer. Use 'install --prefer-source' or 'update --prefer-source' Composer commands to move forward. in C:\wamp\www\Nouveau dossier (2)\vendor\phpoffice\phpword\bootstrap.php on line 22

The path to autoload.php seems ok.

Anyone know why there is this problem ?

After I juste need to copy vendor folder to my network server ? (windows server with wamp)

Thank for your help.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand everything, I'm pretty new to php. I need to create a command on index.php ?

Comment: Is it a default zend-framework project? Then you can not simply call this script in vendor directory from browser - because it is usually not in a public space of the project. How is your project set up?

Comment: it's a simply html/php/css site for my work. I don't use framework. I use phpexcel to create excel (juste downloaded folder from github) but I don't achieve to use phpword.

Comment: Okay, I thought there was some kind of MVC Usage, because of the ZF components (installed via composer). Assuming you have an entry point, e.g. same folder as where your index.php is located: create a word.php, copy contents from examples, include the autoload.php on top, finally call the word.php in browser.

Comment: It seems to work ! Thank !

Comment: I have the same problem. Does anybody have any ideas?